# PHP v5.6 PDO on MS SQL Server 2014

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, php-5.6

### Issue

I am currently unable to connect to my database using PDO in PHP.

---

### Specs

- PHP version 5.6.9
- Database: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 on 2008 R2
- From phpinfo(): PDO drivers: mysql, odbc, sqlite
- Using IIS 6.1

---

### What I've tried

I have just installed the drivers in the SQLSRV32.exe file from Microsoft (from this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) to my PHP extensions folder, however I still cannot seem to connect to my database. (And yes, I restarted IIS)

I can get the connection to work with older connection methods.

---

### My Code

My current PHP code for PDO connection is as follows:

```
try {
    $this->pdo = new PDO('odbc:host='.$this->hostname.':'.$this->port.';dbname='.$this->database,$this->username,$this->password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Failed to get DB handle: '.$e->getMessage().'<br/>';
    exit;
}
```

The above code is inside my MyPDO class constructor so that when I instantiate my class, it is connected `$pdo = new MyPDO();`.

---

### My Code's Result

The issue is that I am getting this error as output:

`Failed to get DB handle: SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

Any help resolving this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you're inadvertently concatenating the username and password into the dsn  (as part of the dbname) rather than passing them in as additional parameters; it should probably be : `new PDO('odbc:host='.$this->hostname.':'.$this->port.';dbname='.$this->database, $this->username, $this->password);`

Comment: My apologies, I updated my post with the correct code. I am still experiencing this issue

Comment: Ok, the basic question, do you want to use ODBC? If so, have you defined this DSN? (I haven't done this since Windows 2000 days, but there used to be a control panel for defining them. One tab for user-specific ones, and another tab for system-wide ones.) Once it's defined [you want to do something like this](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.connection.php): `new PDO("odbc:dsn_name", $user, $pass);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Double check your php.ini and confirm that you have lines:

   ```
   extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
   extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
   ```

   For PDO only **php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll** is mandatory.
2. In phpinfo() in PDO Drivers sections you should have: **sqlsrv**
3. Use PDO_SQLSRV DSN rather than odbc, for example:

   ```
   $this->pdo = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$hostname,$port;Database=$dbname", $username, $password);
   ```

   or if you have full datasource name (ex. localhost\SQLEXPRESS)

   ```
   $this->pdo = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database=$dbname", $username, $password);
   ```

If you receive **could not find driver** exception it means that sqlsrv extensions are not loaded.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you very much. I was missing `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll` in the *php.ini* file and changed my PDO call to your second code chunk using the full datasource name